# A circuit with 2 resistors in series - current in between them

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Let us have this circuit:

[image: Simple "series" circuit]

We know from Kirchhoff's laws that the current I<sub>1</sub> entering R<sub>1</sub> and current I<sub>3</sub> exiting R<sub>3</sub> are the same, I<sub>1</sub>=I<sub>3</sub>.

But the point that bothers me is that: we know according to Ohm's law that the current density J equals to oE, where o is the conductivity of the material.
R<sub>1</sub>, R<sub>2</sub>, and R<sub>3</sub> have different conductivities, so the current density J in each of the resistors should be different, if we assume that the electric field E is constant through the supplier(battery with constant volt V).

Why does the current remain the same?

Comment: Minor comment: conductivity is usually $\sigma$ (on this website, type `$\sigma$`). Upper- and lower-case “o” are generally avoided as variable names; too much like a zero.

Answer (score 2):

> ...so the current density J in each of the resistors should be
> different, if we assume that the electric field E is constant through
> the supplier(battery with constant volt V).

As you already know, Kirchhoff's current law requires that the current into a series circuit equals the current exiting the series circuit. Consequently, the current density in each resistor for a series circuit will only depend on the cross sectional area of each resistor, not on the value of the resistance or the conductivity of its material.

Shown mathematically,

The current density (magnitude) is

$$J=\sigma E$$

For each resistor, assuming uniform cross sectional area, its resistance is

$$R=\rho\frac{L}{A}=\frac{L}{\sigma A}$$

Thus

$$\sigma=\frac{L}{RA}$$

The electric field in each resistor is the voltage gradient in each resistor, or

$$E=\frac{V}{L}$$

From Ohms law, $V=IR$, so

$$E=\frac{IR}{L}$$

Substituting for $\sigma$ and $E$ in the first equation, we have

$$J=\biggl (\frac{L}{RA}\biggl)\biggl(\frac{IR}{L}\biggr)=\frac{I}{A}$$

Indicating the current density in each series resistor depends only on its cross sectional area, not on the value of the resistance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why this scenario is actually not possible?
https://pasteboard.co/3YWpPZHEGpPk.png

two resistors with the same length L and same cross-sectional area A, connected in series and has different conductivities o1 > o2.
as I think of it - the electrons move "faster" in first one and "slower" in second one.
All charges that entering first one exiting the second one, but in different velocities!!

Comment: @mcr0yal The electric field is not the same in both resistors. Since their resistances are different, the voltage drops across each is different. The electric field in each resistor equals the voltage drop divided by the length. Since the lengths are the same, the electric fields have to be different.  Is that clear?

Comment: Kind of, but, my follow-up question is what "causes" different electric field in each resistor? or what "causes" different voltage drops in each one? is that the battery that responsible of "creating" specific voltages according to the resistances?

And, just theoretically, why my scenario is actually not possible?
what would we see "wrong" if the battery was creating a CONSTANT electric field between the first resistor and the second?

Comment: @mcr0yal what causes a different electric field in each resistor is a different ratio of voltage drop to length. What causes different voltage drops in each resistor is Ohms law. For the same current $I$ (which you have for a series circuit) the voltage drop across each resistor is $V_{R1}=IR_1$ and $V_{R2}=IR_2$. The battery creates the total potential (voltage) $V_T$ across both resistors. That voltage is then divided between them according to $$V_{R1}=V_{T}\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}$$ and $$V_{R2}=V_{T}\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}$$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: So do you now accept my answer?

Comment: Yea, I think i got this now.
It's just the battery that "creates" different voltages on different resistances, and it must be that way because there is no build-up of charge nowhere in the circuit.
Different currents in series would mean build-up of charge - something that just doesnt happen.

Comment: @mcr0yal Yes I think you got it now

Answer (score 1):

From $Q=It$  the charge flowing past a point is current x time, and $I = \frac{Q}{t}$

As there is no build up of charge anywhere in the circuit, the charge passing each point is the same, so the current is the same.

In answer to your question about the resistances of $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ being different, this just means that the voltages across the three resistances are different, from Ohm's law, $V=IR$